# How can I choose an element using xpath that has 2 X 2 kinds of structure?

Tags: xpath

This is what the wonderful HTML table in Confluence looks like:

```
<tr>
  <td> key1
  </td>

  <td> key2
  </td>

  <td> value1
  </td>

  <td> value2
  </td>
</tr>
```

I need an xpath that can identify a row based on key1 + key2.

This would be easy by itself right? Now here's the complication with confluence:

> Each row can either contain the value directly inside td, or, it can have a
>   td > span tag which will contain the value.

In other words, each row can be in either of these formats:

```
<td> text
</td>
```

OR,

```
<td>
  <span>
    text
  </span>
</td>
```

Here's where I'm currently at:

```
(//tr[descendant::td[text()='key1' or descendant::span[text()='key1'] ] and descendant::td[text()='key2' or descendant::span[text()='key2'] ]])
```

This doesn't work. It doesn't catch anything.

PS: I've totally not spent half the day trying to grab the different rows! The real problem is more than this but I've solved the second half. The row selection isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below XPath to match *row by values of two cells*:

```
//tr[normalize-space(td)="key1" and normalize-space(td[2])="key2"]
```

Comment: Each of the keys can either be in td or it can be in td/span . I tried out your expression and unfortunately, its not working. Please note that the the logical expression is like this:  (td or span)[key1] and (td or span)[key2] . It would be really great if you could give it a try because no one else has replied to it yet.

Comment: @Mugen , this might not work only if provided piece of HTML differs from the real one, so next time please provide more realistic source code example

Comment: The expression that you provided doesn't look symmetric w.r.t. key1 and key2. However, in the source code key1 and key2 are exactly symmetrical. Perhaps, my question was not clear. Please let me rephrase it once. Each cell can either have a "td" tag OR, a "td/span" tag. This is random. The xpath has to take into account both cases. This applies to key1 as well as key2. Please let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Mugen `normalize-space(td)` means *string representation of table cell (ignoring the leading/trailing spaces)*. It doesn't depend on innerHTML of cell itself, so it covers both cases and it works fine with the source code from question

Comment: I created a new source html file based on the question and tried out your xpath on it. Your code worked flawlessly! I tried out all 4 combinations of the elements and it worked every time. I am really not sure where the source is differing. But since my problem is solved this is the best answer to my question. Thank you for replying!

Comment: @Mugen , Welcome, If it's not working with your real `table`, you can update HTML in your question, so I will edit my solution to be more applicable to your exact case

Comment: How are your skill levels so high in XPATH? It would be great if you could tell me where you've learnt from. Personally, I'm finding XPATH to be an unexpectedly "yuuuuge" field. I wish I could learn everything in one shot from a good source, instead of bits and pieces, so that I can become an expert too.

Comment: @Mugen , [this XPath cheat sheet](http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf) can be a good helper. [Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) for more advanced usage. Also you can use testers [like this one](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) to quickly check your XPath

Comment: W00t! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this! OMG, I can't believe I solved it after putting in hours. It's a very simple solution actually! :)

```
//*[text() = 'key1']/ancestor::tr[descendant::*[text() = 'key2']]
```

This selects the row according to the logical expression { (td=key1 OR td/span=key1) && (td=key2 OR td/span=key2) )